# Accessing flask at localhost:5000 requires sign in Username and Password. Saying Your Connection Is Not Private

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot

So i was trying to do this [project](https://www.hackster.io/hackershack/smart-security-camera-90d7bd) for my homework. It wasnt running smoothly but in the end i figured it out and solve all the problems. When i try to access 192.168.43.2:5000 (my raspberry ip), i was asked to login using a username and password. I thought it was just because i try to access my raspberry from my computer. But when i try localhost:5000, i asked the same.
The question is, what username and password should i entered there? The tutorial didnt metion anything about login password.

P.S : I'm 100% using the codes from [the owner GitHub page](https://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/Smart-Security-Camera), just changing some mail.py file

(im not yet allowed to embed picture)

[Accessing from my Raspberry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyVWJ.png)

[Accessing from my Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HS0T.png)

Edit : Thanks to the comments, the login credentials were in main.py in `CHANGE_ME_USERNAME` and `CHANGE_ME_PLEASE`.

(how do i close this question lol im new)

Comment: Might be faster if you ask the owner via the issue reporting tool on that github repo...

Comment: I am speculating here, but quick look at the code, makes me believe that the login and password are set in the main.py (look for `CHANGE_ME_USERNAME` and `CHANGE_ME_PLEASE`).

Comment: It seems it is defined in main.py: https://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/Smart-Security-Camera/blob/master/main.py#L16-L17

Comment: @jabbson @GinoMempin omg thanks i didnt realize that  the comment said `# App Globals (do not edit)` so i have no courage to edit that

Comment: That should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Should be where the sever is hosted. So, if you are running Flask from your Raspberry Pi, I believe it should be from the user profile that is running the your primary/starting file. i.e. main.py

Comment: I think he did not correctly present the problem. This is not the solution though, but keep on ;)

Comment: Answer is wrong because the original question was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [jabbson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190565/jabbson), the entry point of the program is [main.py](https://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/Smart-Security-Camera/blob/master/main.py). You can see those lines:

```py
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = 'CHANGE_ME_USERNAME'
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'] = 'CHANGE_ME_PLEASE'
```

Contrary to the comment, these **should be edited** with correct login/pass information. However adding hardcoded sensitive information is not recommanded. You should have those info in the running environment. You could have a look at the [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) module for that.